# Data one contition TOP, table with value in DB

Tags: php, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

How Order table with value in DB, works fine order ID but need lines in red (não captado) go in to Top and afther all data.

```
$data = DB::table('home')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: You want to order by red first, and then by ID?

Comment: yes, first what is in red (Não Captado) and then by id..

Comment: So...add that as another order by clause...